# How Application Exceptions work when both parent and child classes are annotated?

Tags: java, exception, jakarta-ee, ejb, ejb-3.1

I'm referring to the ***JSR 318: Enterprise JavaBeansTM,Version 3.1*** in this questions.

In chapter 14 (Exception Handling). Below example is there. And I understand it.

```
@ApplicationException(rollback=true)
public class ExceptionA extends RuntimeException

public class ExceptionB extends ExceptionA

@ApplicationException(inherited=false, rollback=false)
public class ExceptionC extends ExceptionB

public class ExceptionD extends ExceptionC

ExceptionA is an application exception with transaction rollback.

ExceptionB is an application exception with transaction rollback.

ExceptionC is an application exception without transaction rollback.

ExceptionD is not an application exception.
```

My question is what happens when classes are annotated as below and ExceptionB is thrown? Will the transaction be rolled back?

```
@ApplicationException
public class ExceptionA extends RuntimeException

@ApplicationException(rollback=true)
public class ExceptionB extends ExceptionA
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example (or question),

```
@ApplicationException // rollback attribute defaults to false, so tx will no rollback
public class ExceptionA extends RuntimeException

@ApplicationException(rollback=true) // tx will be marked for rollback
public class ExceptionB extends ExceptionA
```

Another relevant point, is that, by default, `RuntimeExceptions` always mark the transaction for roll back! So, you need be careful about them ... let me explain:

```
// Because it is not annotated, applies default behaviour... this is,
// the exception will be wrapped in EJB Exception and the transaction
// will marked for rollback (because it is a RuntimeException)
public class ExceptionA extends RuntimeException {
}

// The exception will be thrown like it is (not wrapped)
// and the tx will no marked for roll back (even if it is a RuntimeException)
// rollback defaults to false and inherited attribute defaults to true
@ApplicationException
public class ExceptionB extends ExceptionA {
}
```